# Output top few records by date using kdb

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery, qsqltablemodel

Suppose I have a table, with date, sym, and size as columns.  Dates are in ascending order and sizes are in descending order for each date.  How do I abridge the table, such that each date, only top few, say 10, records are kept?  The simpler the command the better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Given a table:

```
q)show tbl:`date`val!/:(.z.d+til 3) cross 100+til 25;
    date       val
    --------------
    2016.10.31 100
    2016.10.31 101
    2016.10.31 102
    2016.10.31 103
    2016.10.31 104
    ..
```

Select first N rows by date: (N=2 in below example)

```
q)select from tbl where i in{raze y sublist/:group x}[date;2]
    date       val
    --------------
    2016.10.31 100
    2016.10.31 101
    2016.11.01 100
    2016.11.01 101
    2016.11.02 100
    2016.11.02 101
```

Uses [`group`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dictsandtables/#group) function - which will return  a dictionary containing indices where each unique value occurs. The function then retrieves the first N indices ([sublist](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#sublist)) for each unique value.

NB: `i` is the implicit row index in a kdb table.

Answer (score 2):

'fby' is also a good option and is generally used in such cases where operation/aggregation on group is required.

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#fby

In your example, since table already has 'size' col  in decending order for each date so fetching top 10 rows will give the desired result.

```
q) select from tbl where ({x in 10#x};i) fby date
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `fby` is the best solution, there is another way to get the same results :

```
ungroup select sublist[3] size by date from tbl
```

However, with multiple columns this won't be a cleaner approach :

```
ungroup select sublist[3] size ,sublist[3] sym ,sublist[3] price  by date from tbl
```